# Getting width and height of element outside the DOM in JS

Tags: javascript, dom

```
function createCloudEntry(termName, fontSize) {
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerText = termName;
  div.style.fontSize = fontSize + "px";
  div.style.position = "absolute";
  div.style.display = "inline-block";
  div.style.top = getRandomPosition(0, cloudHeight - 40) + 'px';
  div.style.left = getRandomPosition(0, cloudWidth - 150) + 'px';

//document.write("Left: " + getRandomPosition(0, parseInt(cloudHeight)) + ", Top: " +   getRandomPosition(0, parseInt(cloudWidth)) + "<br/>");
//document.write(div.style.width + " | " + div.style.height + "<br/>");

  return div;
```

}

So this is my function where i just create a new div with some css properties. My question is can I get the width and height of the element SO FAR (after adding text with certain font size), before it is added to the DOM? I tried window.getComputedStyle() but it didn't work, div.style.width/height doesn't work, too.

Comment: What do you mean ? An element has no size outside the DOM and the point where you insert it may have consequences of the resulting size. What are you trying to achieve ? Why don't you simply add the element to the DOM ?

Comment: Because I need to know how much space it would occupy for the getRandomPosition() function where I get random values for top and left properties based on its size.

Comment: Then add it to the dom, store the dimensions and remove it from the dom again. The browser won't repaint in between so this won't be visible to the user.

Comment: That works too, but I've come with solution about 10 mins after I posted. I added them all to the DOM and since I was adding them to a wrapper element, I traversed them as childs and added the top and left properties.

Answer (score 1):

I use something like this to temporarily add it to the DOM and then remove it right after I've pulled the values.

```
function getElementSizing(e)
{
    document.body.appendChild(e);
    var s = {client:{w:e.clientWidth, h:e.clientHeight}, offset:{w:e.offsetWidth, h:e.offsetHeight}, scroll:{w:e.scrollWidth, h:e.scrollHeight}};
    document.body.removeChild(e);
    return s;
}
```

The values will vary depending on the type of element, it's positioning (absolute, relative) style and content so you will want to expand it to meet your needs.

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerText = 'some text';
div.style.fontSize = 12 + "px";
div.style.position = "absolute";
div.style.display = "inline-block";

var myDivSize = getElementSizing(div);

console.log('DIV Client Width: '+myDivSize.client.w);//returns 46 in chrome.
console.log('DIV Client Height: '+myDivSize.client.h);//returns 16 in chrome.
console.log('DIV Offset Width: '+myDivSize.offset.w);//returns 46 in chrome.
console.log('DIV Offset Height: '+myDivSize.offset.h);//returns 16 in chrome.
console.log('DIV Scroll Width: '+myDivSize.scroll.w);//returns 46 in chrome.
console.log('DIV Scroll Height: '+myDivSize.scroll.h);//returns 16 in chrome.
```

Hope that helps!